# directed graphs that have m vertices

Tags: graph-theory

does there exist a simple directed graph on m vertices ($\forall m \geq1 $) that has no loops and has $(m-1)^2$ edges and is not strong? what about one with $(m-1)(m-2)$ edges that is not weak?
If they do, present an example.

for the first one, I thought of a tree which has m-1 edges, but I cannot think of any relation to it. does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

- What is the maximum number $M_e$ of edges in a simple directed graph on $m$ vertices?
- if $M_e$ is smaller than your desired number of edges, can this exist?
- If it is larger, can you throw some edges away?

Comment: @mandella assuming you allow parallel but opposite direction edges and no loops, yes that is correct.  If you were to not allow even those then the maximum number of edges is the same as for simple graphs (*undirected*).

Comment: @JMoravitz, yes that is the case, i have no loops and one vertex can be at most once a tail and a head.

Comment: @mandella "*but which ones would be a good choice*" It doesn't really matter, does it?  We are only asked to prove the existence of the graph, but we don't need to know anything else specific about it.  We don't need to know which edges exist and where, just the number of edges.  So long as you start with the graph with the most edges and throw *literally any* edges away so long as they are the right number of edges, it will work.

Comment: @mandella throw out any edges you like, it makes no difference

Comment: If you want a clearly and well defined example then come up with some specific way of labeling and ordering the edges and remove the first however many of them.  For example, use Lexicographic Ordering on the edges.  If that is unsatisfactory, then try playing with making one or more vertices special and having either no incoming edges to that vertex or no edges at all touching that vertex.